# How can i convert Double in a json to string in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Input is of type: `{amount: 11139072.00, currency: "USD"}`
I am trying to extract a double value from a JSON and converting into spark SQL. It is not working for me.
For smaller values like 20.00, 100.00 it works fine, but for larger values like 11139072.00 it is converted to 1.1139072E7.
How can I get this working ?

I have tried `cast(double as string)` and `cast(double as STRING)`
I have tried `string(double)`
None of the above works

Answer (score 0):

Cast to `decimal(18, 2)`.

```
scala> df.withColumn("amount", $"amount".cast("decimal(18, 2)")).show(false)
+-----------+--------+
|amount     |currency|
+-----------+--------+
|11139072.00|USD     |
+-----------+--------+
```